# How to make chat(whatsapp like) ui in java swing using MigLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, miglayout

I want to add components to MigLayout which i can add as sent/recieved message, just like this:

```
--------------------------------------------
| received message                         |

|                              sent Message|
--------------------------------------------
```

I have created following constructor:

```
new MigLayout(
        // set the automatic wrap after columns
        "insets 0, wrap 0", 
        // hardcode fixed column width and fixed column gap 
        "", 
        // hardcode fixed height and a zero row gap
        "[]10"));
```

while adding a component if i use "push, al right" it doest the job for me but the components take average space of height as shown in link below:

[image]

so all i want is these components one after another with only gap specified(10) in constructor.
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. I think you are new to swing. If yes, then go with JavaFx. Using JavaFx you can create better UI.

Comment: I know but i want to use swing only. Other layout will also work in swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like:

```
JPanel parent = JPanel( new BorderLayout() );
parent.add(yourPanelUsingMigLayout, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
frame.add(parent);
```

The BorderLayout.PAGE_START will respect the preferred height of the component. Therefore you should not see vertical space between components.